# How to input the data set in for doc2vec in Keras and train

Tags: keras, out-of-memory, gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

I have a data-set that contains search queries terms and the ids of the users that typed/searched for those queries.
I want to get a user-embedding (user2vec) sort of thing to learn to  the type of thing the users search for.

Previously, I merged all the queries for each user id and tokenized it and tagged it using `gensim.doc2vec` Tagged function.

when, I tried using `gensim.doc2vec` to learn the embedding i kept getting memory error each time I run it.

I want to do it this time with Keras but don't know how input my data and how to do it.

I want to output to show a matrix `m` by `n`
where `m`, is the number of users 
`n`, is the dimension of the embedding(30)